# jQuery : get id of element that contains text

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I am trying to get the ID of an element after the following actions :

I click on a link, and get the text in it. Then I want to compare that text to get an element that contains it.

And get that newly found element's id.

However the latest action returns me an undefined result, so your help is welcome.

Here is my code :

```js
 $("#mybutton").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var txt = $(e.target).text();
    var findTxt = $(".list:contains('txt')");

   console.log("findTxt returns :  "+ findTxt.attr('id'));

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="mybutton">Sample Text</a>
  <span id="idtofind" class="list">Sample Text</span>
  <span id="another" class="list">another</span>
  <span id="andanother" class="list">and another</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an element which contains the literal text "txt" - what you want is to find the element which contains the text *stored in the variable `txt`*

```js
$("#mybutton").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var txt = $(e.target).text();
    var findTxt = $(".list:contains('" + txt + "')");

   console.log("findTxt returns :  "+ findTxt.attr('id'));

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="mybutton">Sample Text</a>
  <span id="idtofind" class="list">Sample Text</span>
  <span id="another" class="list">another</span>
  <span id="andanother" class="list">and another</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the string 'txt' instead of passing the variable.

Replace `$(".list:contains('txt')");` with `$(".list:contains('" + txt + "')");`

Like this:

```
 $("#mybutton").click(function (e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var txt = $(e.target).text();
     var findTxt = $(".list:contains('" + txt + "')");
     console.log("findTxt returns :  "+ findTxt.attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(".list:contains('txt')");` should be `$(".list:contains('"+txt+"')");`  Notice the string and the variable concatenation. Below should work :) :

```js
 $("#mybutton").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
   var txt = $(e.target).text();
    var findTxt = $(".list:contains('"+txt+"')");

   console.log("findTxt returns :  "+ findTxt.attr('id'));

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="mybutton">Sample Text</a>
  <span id="idtofind" class="list">Sample Text</span>
  <span id="another" class="list">another</span>
  <span id="andanother" class="list">and another</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#mybutton").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var txt = $(this).text();
  var findTxt = $(".list").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == txt
  })
  console.log("findTxt returns :  " + findTxt.attr("id"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="mybutton">Sample Text</a>
<span id="idtofind" class="list">Sample Text</span>
<span id="another" class="list">another</span>
<span id="andanother" class="list">and another</span>
```

Use `.filter()`

Comment: `filter` returns a jQuery object - no need to wrap it again in `$()`.

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe due to my comment (which you've not fixed BTW)

Comment: but even though it is closed in `$()` it still works anyway

Comment: Yes, but its entirely unnecessary (and slow). Anyway, Ive upvoted to cancel your downvote. `filter` is a good way to do this as the contains pseudo selector is very slow.

Comment: anyway thanks for explaining now i wont make the same mistake @Jamiec

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="mybutton">Sample Text</a>
<span id="idtofind" class="list">Sample Text</span>
<span id="another" class="list">another</span>
<span id="andanother" class="list">and another</span>
```

-

```
$("#mybutton").click(function (e){
   var txt = $(this).text();
   var findTxt = $(".list:contains("+txt+")");
   console.log("findTxt returns :  "+ findTxt.attr('id'));
 });
```

Since you're within the scope of the button that is clicked, you can simply use `this` to refer to the button.

Also, to have a proper link you need to use the `href` attribute in HTML. Simply use `href="#"` and there is also no need for the `e.preventDefault()`.